# How to bypass re-captcha with gocolly twocaptcha and selenium

Tags: selenium, go, selenium-chromedriver, go-colly

After several request my **scraping** code blocked by target site with re-captcha. I use https://github.com/gocolly/twocaptcha to bypass captcha with selenium chrome driver. It works while bypass with selenium chrome driver but when I run my **scraping** code again and it still blocked.

my question :

1. Why my code still blocked when re-captcha already bypassed with
   selenium chrome driver?
2. How to bypass this re-captcha block?

Comment: Did you write to the service 2captcha in the ticket? Perhaps they will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAPTCHA, short for Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart, is explicitly designed to prevent automation, so do not try! There are two primary strategies to get around CAPTCHA checks:

Disable CAPTCHAs in your test environment
Add a hook to allow tests to bypass the CAPTCHA